# Powershell Set-AzureStorageBlobContent Fails

Tags: powershell

I am using Set-AzureStorageBlobContent in Powershell script to upload multiple files[bak] in a loop to blob storage. The issue is that the script runs successfully when I run manually using Powershell IDE. However, it fails when I run it through SQL agent job.I have tried to catch the exception but it seems that the script crashes. The first file in the loop get uploaded. I have tried including delay/Wait in the loop but of no help.
Below is the code snippet.I have tried ErrorAction [Ignore/Stop] but no use.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storagename -StorageAccountKey $key 

Loop{
    Try { 
        Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -BlobType Page -Blob $nm -Container backups -File $fn -Context $context -Force 
    }

    Catch {
        Log exception
    }
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that the script launches, that it goes authenticate properly to azure? I mean in the SQL context

Comment: Yes, before begning upload, I have code to delete the same files in a loop using Remove-AzureStorageBlob and it works fine.
Only difference I can see is that during manual execution, the scripts waits for upload [There is a status displaying] while by automating, the script moves without any delay.